# How to save file programatically in WEB-INF resources in java?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, web

The environment is MAVEN-based WILDFLY container.

I can retrieve the URI of file as

```
Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/images/nir.png");
```

how can I programmatically add a file on that folder?

I did something like this:

```
Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/text/");
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(newjava.io.File(loader.getFile()+"1.txt"));
//add something on 1.txt, save it on web-inf folder!!
```

and from web, if I had to connect to this. Why am I not able to do so?

like, to access to server

```
http://server/text/1.txt
```

Why doesn't it work this way?

Comment: Anything under WEB-INF is not directly accessible to the browser.

Comment: wait? I had put static img as WEB-INF/1.png, and I could access that as <img src = "/1.png" /> I want to write on that folder, or create subfolder temporarily, to save some files for a while...

Comment: It is a best practice NOT to serve content from WEB-INF as that allows attackers to see your code. However, there are certainly servers that allow it. I would consider them misconfigured.

Comment: Anything you put there will be lost on the next deployment. Don't do this. The resource system should be considered as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. But it's not recommend

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/../");
File file = new File(path);
String fullPathToYourWebappRoot = file.getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: Why isn't this recommended method?

Comment: WEB-INF is not the place where you can store file on run.

Comment: Which place is recommended instead?

Comment: You can store in server,If you have lots of file is there you can go for file server.

Comment: (`"/..."` with a starting backslash is as I always did it.) Maybe "/WEB-INF/files/...". Use `getResource` only for read-only template files, to be copied.